# Matplotlib: make a 3D scatter plot from list of 2D plot coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

I have 600 2D image slices that I want to compile into a 3D image. Instead of working with the original data, however, I have converted each z-slice into a 2D array of threshold data using scikit-image's find_boundaries function. Running:

```
list_of_data[0].shape
```

gives me `(1900, 1850)`

Each array is a list of 0/1 values: [0, 0, 0, 1...0]

I have now converted every image within the list into a set of 2D coordinates using np.where:

```
zstack = []
for zslice in list_of_data:
    zstack.append(np.where(zslice == 1))
```

What I can't figure out is how to merge this list of 2D coordinates into one list of 3D coordinates.

Comment: A scatter plot takes *coordinates*. You can use your boolean array to index a coordinate array.

Comment: ty. Making the coordinate array - `xaxis = np.arange(stack.shape[0])
    yaxis = np.arange(stack.shape[1])`. Could you show me an example of indexing this array with the bool array? I'm guessing it may involve np.where?